# pod install returns fatal error: SSL certificate issue?

Tags: git, curl, ssl, cocoapods

I just installed CocoaPods by following these instructions:

Now I opened an Xcode project which has CocoaPods in it, I opened the terminal, went into that project folder and typed "pod install" as required, and I am getting an error back:

```
$ pod install
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] Pod::Executable clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master

Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:217:in `rescue in run': undefined method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:210:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what this is about. Can someone help me? This is the first time I try to do anything with CocoaPods on OS X Mavericks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Github's SSL certificate looks fine from my end, but maybe you have distrusted it for some reason, or you are using a proxy.  To resolve:

Using the Safari browser (not Chrome, Firefox or Opera) on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) visit https://github.com (no `www.`).

If an alert pops up, press the "Show Certificate" button, check "Always Trust", and then "Continue."

If no alert pops up, press the green or gray Security button by the URL:

> [image]

Then make sure "Always trust" is checked on the certificate.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, try temporarily disabling any proxy servers you might be running, such as Charles.

After that, `pod install` should work.

Note: A portion of my answer text was copied [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706191/1445366).

Comment: It fixed the issue! pod install was just very very slow at first and I thought it was still not working after this step. Thanks Aaron!

Comment: @Mathieu I always use `pod install --verbose` so I can see the progress, otherwise I get impatient.

Comment: It appears that the always trust button is no longer there in 10.9.2. My GitHub cert is no longer trusted, even though it was fine yesterday.

Comment: Had a similar issue trying to clone from Stash. Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208426/getting-ssl-error-when-attempting-to-clone-a-stash-repository.

Answer (score 9):

Under the hood `pod` uses just a regular git, so disabling SSL validation for git will solve the problem:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already have installed Cocoapods then write following code in terminal

```
sudo gem update
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in your terminal;

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Answer (score 0):

My Digicert Certificate was twice in the keychain and the used one was invalid. **Deleting the expired one did the job**. Thanks for point me there!

Answer (score 0):

when I run pod install, I encountered the problem :
 !] Pod::Executable clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master

Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain

And I finally resolved it by deleting expired certificates in keychains.
When I open my terminal and run command pod install, it finally succeeded.

Hope It helps

Comment: Delete them, how?