# Pod update error on m1 (realm certificate)

Tags: ios, ssl, cocoapods, apple-m1

I'm trying to run a project on a mac with m1. Installed brew and quietly installed cocoapods. There are only two pods in the project - Realm Swift and Revenue Act.
When installing Realm Swift, the following error occurs:

[image]

**RevenueCat was installed without any problems.** What could be the problem?

*Below in duplicate for convenience*

> Update all pods
> Updating local specs repositories
> Analyzing dependencies
> Downloading dependencies
> Installing Realm (10.33.0)
> [!] /bin/bash -c
> set -e
> sh scripts/setup-cocoapods.sh

> Downloading dependency: 12.13.0 from https://static.realm.io/downloads/core/realm-monorepo-xcframework-v12.13.0.tar.xz
> Downloading core failed:
> https://static.realm.io/downloads/core/realm-monorepo-xcframework-v12.13.0.tar.xz
> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
> More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
> establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
> how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I entered **this command** into the terminal:

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

*The information is taken [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72713507/16517701) answer.*